# Counting within buffers using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer, tools, mapping

I am working on a project where I am trying to map affordable housing and bus stops.

I have used the buffer tool to find out how many bus stops are there within a one mile radius of each affordable house but is there a way to count the bus stops in that one mile radius?

I want to say near X affordable house, there are Y bus stops. Right now what I have is a circle indicating the one mile radius but no count of the number of bus stops in that area.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the "Select by Location" tool as mentioned [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm) in the Esri documentation.

At the top of your application go the selection tab then:

> Click Selection > Select By Location to open the Select by Location dialog box.

Here is a sample follow through that you can use with your datasets

So your select from freatures would be the bus stops

[image]

Your select from source is the buffer

[image]

You could also use the different select by location methods such as the

**Are within a distance**

[image]

**Contain**
[image]